# Define interface as any but with guaranteed properties?

Tags: typescript

I'm hitting an API that returns a list of images in the following structure:

```
{
  "photos": {
    "1": "PHOTOS/1.jpg",
    "3": "PHOTOS/3.jpg",
    "4": "PHOTOS/4.jpg",
    "primary": "PHOTOS/X/PRI.jpg"
  },
  "sketches": {
    "1": "SKETCHES/X/1.jpg",
    "3": "SKETCHES/X/3.jpg",
    "4": "SKETCHES/X/4.jpg"
  }
}
```

The basic contract is that `photos.primary` always exists, all other properties on `photos` are numerical IDs, and for every ID in `photos` there's a matching ID in `sketches`. The IDs are not guaranteed to be continuous.

I would like to set up an interface called something like `ImageIndex` that knows that `photos.primary` is a field but also that any other field is acceptable. I know I could just mark photos and sketches as `any` but for the sake of intellisense I think it'd be worthwhile to define `primary`'s existence.

I tried using an Intersection type like so:

```
export interface PropertyImageIndex {
  photos: ContainsPrimary&any;
  sketches: any;
}

interface ContainsPrimary {
  primary: string;
}
```

but when VSCode would normally show it's intellisense suggestions, there's nothing. This seems to indicate that `any` prevails over the explicit `ImageList` type of `photos` and I lose all suggestions.

Is there a way to tell typescript "this object has AT LEAST these fields, but also has any other fields I might ask it for" in a way that the guaranteed fields will show up as intellisense suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly:

```
interface Photos {
    primary: string;
    [name: string]: string;
}

interface PropertyImageIndex {
    photos: Photos;
    sketches?: { [name: string]: string };
}

let a: Photos = {}; // error
let b: Photos = { primary: "" };
let c: Photos = { primary: "", a: 3 }; // error
let d: Photos = { primary: "", a: "" };

let e: PropertyImageIndex = { photos: { primary: "" } };
let f: PropertyImageIndex = { photos: { primary: "" }, sketches: {} };
let g: PropertyImageIndex = { photos: { primary: "" }, sketches: { key: "" } };
let h: PropertyImageIndex = { photos: { primary: "" }, sketches: { key: 4 } }; // error
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Photos%20%7B%0A%09primary%3A%20string%3B%0A%09%5Bname%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20PropertyImageIndex%20%7B%0A%09photos%3A%20Photos%3B%0A%09sketches%3F%3A%20%7B%20%5Bname%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20a%3A%20Photos%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0Alet%20b%3A%20Photos%20%3D%20%7B%20primary%3A%20%22%22%20%7D%3B%0Alet%20c%3A%20Photos%20%3D%20%7B%20primary%3A%20%22%22%2C%20a%3A%203%20%7D%3B%0Alet%20d%3A%20Photos%20%3D%20%7B%20primary%3A%20%22%22%2C%20a%3A%20%22%22%20%7D%3B%0A%0Alet%20e%3A%20PropertyImageIndex%20%3D%20%7B%20photos%3A%20%7B%20primary%3A%20%22%22%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0Alet%20f%3A%20PropertyImageIndex%20%3D%20%7B%20photos%3A%20%7B%20primary%3A%20%22%22%20%7D%2C%20sketches%3A%20%7B%7D%20%7D%3B%0Alet%20g%3A%20PropertyImageIndex%20%3D%20%7B%20photos%3A%20%7B%20primary%3A%20%22%22%20%7D%2C%20sketches%3A%20%7B%20key%3A%20%22%22%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0Alet%20h%3A%20PropertyImageIndex%20%3D%20%7B%20photos%3A%20%7B%20primary%3A%20%22%22%20%7D%2C%20sketches%3A%20%7B%20key%3A%204%20%7D%20%7D%3B)

Comment: This is what I'm after! Just that `sketches` isn't optional but that's an easy fix.